# Counter incrementing by one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a **function component** that looks like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const incrementThreeTimes = () => {
    incrementCount();
    incrementCount();
    incrementCount();
  }

return (
    <>
         <button onClick={() => incrementThreeTimes()}>+3</button>
    </>
   );
}
export default App;
```

I have a **counter state** that initially is at 0, a function that increments it by one, and I'd like to write a function that increments it by 3.

However, the function that should increment by 3, it increments only by 1. What is the reason for this? Are each of the functions referencing the same global value of 0?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 3):

because setState function is async

you can get actual value using callback:

```
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(prevValue => prevValue + 1);
  };

  const incrementThreeTimes = () => {
    incrementCount();
    incrementCount();
    incrementCount();
  }

return (
    <>
         <button onClick={() => incrementThreeTimes()}>+3</button>
    </>
   );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: So the reason has to do with sync/async? In my research over the matter it always mentioned closures. Thank you for the answer!